# Error in Creating an Index in NEST 2.3.1 (Elastic Search)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, delegates, nest

I'm using NEST 2.3.1 in my .NET Project.

I'm very new to it.

As I Saw in one tutorial I have done this code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Elastic_ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Uri node;
        public static ConnectionSettings settings;
        public static ElasticClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
            settings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
            client = new ElasticClient(settings);
            settings.DefaultIndex("my_blog");

            var indexSettings = new IndexSettings();
            indexSettings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
            indexSettings.NumberOfShards = 1;

            client.CreateIndex(c => c
                .Index("my_blog")
                .InitializeUsing(indexSettings)
                .AddMapping<Post>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));
        }
    }
}
```

But It is not working and I'm getting this error:

> Error  CS1660  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'IndexName' because it is not a delegate type

at the line:

```
client.CreateIndex(c => c
                    .Index("my_blog")
                    .InitializeUsing(indexSettings)
                    .AddMapping<Post>(m => m.MapFromAttributes()));
```

I have tried Searching on Google but I'm only getting Help for Older Version!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This looks like NEST 1.x API which is slightly different from NEST 2.x. You can find documentation for NEST 2.x on the elastic site: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html

Comment: Yeah! Thank You So Much! @RussCam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying old methods with new ElasticSearch Nest.
Your code will work with NEST Ver. 1.X.
Update your code for newer version or you can Use older version of NEST.

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri node        = new Uri(ES_ADDRESS);
var settings    = new ConnectionSettings(node);
settings.DisableDirectStreaming();//Check json
var client      = new ElasticClient(settings);
//Analyzers:
CustomAnalyzer shingles = new CustomAnalyzer
{
  Tokenizer = "standard",
  Filter = new List<string>()
  {
    "standard", "lowercase", "shingle"
  }
};
//Settings for index:
var mapperTemplate = new CreateIndexDescriptor(string.Format("customers"))
  .Settings(s => s
    .Analysis(a => a
      .Analyzers(an => an
        .UserDefined("analyzer_shingles", shingles)
      )
    )
  );
var customer = mapperTemplate.Mappings(ms => ms
  .Map<customers>(m => m
    .AllField(a => a.Analyzer("analyzer_shingles"))
    .AutoMap()
  )
);

//Create index:
var response = client.CreateIndex(customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

with last version this snipet works:

```
var indexCreated = client.CreateIndex("person",
                 s => s.Mappings(ms => ms
                 .Map<Person>(m => m)));
```